# CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - VersionsNestedStack

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy to the server. But, it is failing too often. When I deploy so many times, it is succeeding once. The log is added below. Please look into the issue and help me solve this.

```
E:\projects\project-name\app>serverless deploy --stage sai --verbose
Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)
Serverless: DOTENV: Loading environment variables from ./environments/.env.sai:
Serverless: - DB_HOST_NAME
Serverless: - DB_PORT
Serverless: - DB_USER_NAME
Serverless: - DB_PASSWORD
Serverless: - DB_NAME
Serverless: - POOL_ID
Serverless: - POOL_NAME
Serverless: - POOL_ARN
Serverless: - ADMIN

Serverless: Compiling with Typescript...
Serverless: Using local tsconfig.json
Serverless: Typescript compiled.
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: Summary: 180 resources migrated in to 3 nested stacks
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: Resources per stack:
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: - (root): 252
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: - APINestedStack: 56
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: - PermissionsNestedStack: 62
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: - VersionsNestedStack: 62
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service newteledoc.zip file to S3 (53.75 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
........
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
  CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarConfirmOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentExportOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarDelete
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientlistDashfilterGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeAddPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashuploadOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentDashdashboardOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodNotificationsPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentFilterOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodNotificationsDashcountOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - VersionsNestedStack
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationCreatePost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentGlobalsearchGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEditDashuserPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeAddPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationLocationidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodHelloGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodQuetriggerOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodNotificationsPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodUserDashmailPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodCreateDashpatientPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarBlockGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceInvoiceidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodForgotDashpasswordPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotBlockOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodCompletetmsAppointmentidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSqstriggeredhandlerGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPatientidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashdeleteDelete
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentFilterGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodForgotDashpasswordOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodNotificationsDashcountGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarBlockOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodUserDashmailOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodProfileGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodUserPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeePost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSqstriggeredhandlerOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAvailabilityGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeEmployeeidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarConfirmPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodProfileEditPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodReferenceOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceFilterOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentExportPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - PermissionsNestedStack
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentGlobalsearchOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminDashcheckOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceInvoiceidVarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodUserOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodQuetriggerGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationEditPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashdeleteOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceFilterGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoicePost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentDashdashboardPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodReferenceGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotBlockPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodCreateDashpatientOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashuploadPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarLastDashvalidPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientlistDashfilterGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeLocationsGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeEmployeeidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPatientidVarGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarReminderGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationLocationidVarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodProfileOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodDeleteDashadminpatientDelete
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeePermissionsGet
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientDashsearchPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationCreatePost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAddPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminDashcheckPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarDelete
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarPut
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEditDashuserOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodHelloOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentPost
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSqstriggeredappointmentreminderhandlerGet
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - newteledoc-sai
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - newteledoc-sai
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodCompletetmsAppointmentidVarOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodForgotDashpasswordPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationEditOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeePermissionsGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSqstriggeredhandlerGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodCreateDashpatientPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceFilterOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentFilterOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceInvoiceidVarOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeAddPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashdeleteOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPatientidVarGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeePost
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodDeleteDashadminpatientOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarReminderGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodCompletetmsAppointmentidVarPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashuploadOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationCreatePost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentDashdashboardOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashdeleteDelete
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationEditPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeePermissionsOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPatientidVarOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodNotificationsOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodLocationLocationidVarOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoicePost
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentExportOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodFileDashuploadPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEditDashuserPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarConfirmPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodDeleteDashadminpatientDelete
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodInvoiceInvoiceidVarGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotBlockPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAppointmentAppointmentidVarLastDashvalidOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientPatientidVarPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodProfileEditPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAddOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodNotificationsDashcountGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodForgotDashpasswordOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminpatientDashsearchPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodCompletetmsAppointmentidVarOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeEmployeeidVarPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarBlockGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodDeleteDashadminpatientOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodProfileGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEditDashuserPut
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodEmployeeAddPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodAdminappointmentAppointmentidVarReminderGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodReferenceGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotBlockOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodQuetriggerGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::SQS::Queue - PDFGenerationQueue
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodUserOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping - SQSTriggeredAppointmentReminderHandlerEventSourceMappingSQSSaiPDFGenerationQueue
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSqstriggeredhandlerOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodUserDashmailOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodReferenceOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarDelete
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSlotSlotidVarBlockOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodProfileEditOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodUserDashmailPost
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSqstriggeredappointmentreminderhandlerGet
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodSqstriggeredappointmentreminderhandlerOptions
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethodPatientPatientidVarOptions
...................
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::SQS::Queue - pendingAppointmentQueue
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - newteledoc-sai
Serverless: Operation failed!
Serverless: View the full error output: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A435341932277%3Astack%2Fnewteledoc-sai%2Fb4639750-6f4e-11eb-9626-12da74e87777

Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

An error occurred: VersionsNestedStack - Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:435341932277:stack/newteledoc-sai-VersionsNestedStack-181I5TGABKF2D/46ab9990-6f50-11eb-81ea-0e6bd0a701a5 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AddDashuserLambdaVersionhb1AmzoUEBTZeWeqIG7iBZCLWtOV1j9bR5SE8txKQ, EmployeeDashlistLambdaVersiondIAyuzakA5wU8oYoSGWfnnHBTEGkJQNGGEicLwprMo, AdminDashappointmentDashdeleteDashblockDashslotLambdaVersionmyI2Y3jOeDluxSwHQzmM17kIOcDAHUStrQXbLGbboc, AdminDashappointmentDashdetailsLambdaVersionca63NnVxS0oOSiXb47sBYlGUMYHzZyps63wvNhRkJU, HelloLambdaVersionqPrtVuvHEGsGIp7BrkbGuAcLVkRRETSf4Y9MJj5e20, GetDashavailabilityLambdaVersion4plxfrwztmYiXqc8yeDt0gXhe4ZaMe1UGfaRRZKo, ValidateDashlastDashappointmentLambdaVersionFo8U1RLkzK9siH1DkQqZRrAkUwCzCRyHuUOqPHw, NotificationsDashlistLambdaVersionij3N3MnJfBYfY7ZqYKRUhNv76SDoOwU3Z2d60U7iN1I, ConfirmDashappointmentLambdaVersionBj0y74aBb7Drzvq6bGJuKUpgM1NWLmxu6vnBSwNaKw, ForgotDashpasswordLambdaVersionyAnqC5H5P0Jzku5nReGgpuxlqXfuMC03ncQpggxumdo]. .

Get Support --------------------------------------------
Docs: docs.serverless.com
Bugs: github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
Issues: forum.serverless.com

Your Environment Information ---------------------------
Operating System: win32
Node Version: 14.15.0
Framework Version: 2.11.0 (local)
Plugin Version: 4.1.2
SDK Version: 2.3.2
Components Version: 3.3.0
```

**EDIT:**
Event from the cloudformation

```
Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:435341932277:stack/newteledoc-sai-VersionsNestedStack-11JZ3AQSV9FY6/44ab2d50-6f5e-11eb-8ae3-123e22873efd was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [SubmitDashtmsformLambdaVersionHEdTaVJVedX2H4dVFGNE4D5xEYhJvpKqjcGR88PuvXs, WorkingDashlocationsLambdaVersionhwV0mmrGfJ3m9s0tVTBTSaAws9KoMHKtIQUXzBgXc, InvoiceDashdetailsLambdaVersionlUAKZVSwJAIr1dnYX6loluCQocr51EXcnCfzhgSLIw, LocationDasheditLambdaVersion7n7JtdwrsIclcnGduRy6ScAjbT2ocz2habskGNyA4, InvoiceDashlistLambdaVersionj0CHc4VmUfmtxOkwjxIOPM6t5KAjVrqxqhQtNZoc, EmployeeDashlistLambdaVersiondIAyuzakA5wU8oYoSGWfnnHBTEGkJQNGGEicLwprMo, EditDashpatientLambdaVersionrC7dFiz5N2WmsKa7aFzkKOrqE9yxg7vQdgpveV7O74, HelloLambdaVersionqPrtVuvHEGsGIp7BrkbGuAcLVkRRETSf4Y9MJj5e20, InvoiceDashlistDashfilterLambdaVersionmmEJBqn0IN0TNJbWHZRB9M6CEp6BPkwO2cXuBL5Q, IsDashadminLambdaVersionn5srvspY7LyVkOLrhwdkF8vifCY7E0DZ8mCL9lEHW0, AppointmentDashlistLambdaVersionM0V60iEuTTosBsFG1JhnhoLpNSu4UW8JUa4cbbHoF
```

Thank you...

Comment: Can you go to CloudFormation console, and check `Events` for your stack. Should have more info why it fails.

Comment: @Marcin , I checked it. I did not understand the reason. I have updated my question and added the event log. Can you please check and help me?

Comment: If its nested stack you should check nested stack events.

Comment: @Marcin , where can I see nested stack events? Can you please guide me.

Comment: In the CloduFormation console, you have to toggle `View nested`.

Comment: @Marcin , `View nested` is enabled. And showing the above added log only. Can you please tell me how can I see the complete log?

Comment: Sadly, for now I don't know more ideas :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228728/discussion-between-sai-and-marcin).

Comment: @Sai The log you posted isn't of much use because it just says what failed rather than why it failed. You need to go to your actual nested stack "newteledoc-sai-VersionsNestedStack-11JZ3AQSV9FY6" in the CF console, go to the Events tab, find the first failure, and it will tell you why it failed. If you can't see the stack then change the filter to Deleted stacks and you will see it.